# mysql query based on checkboxes and input boxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, input

So I'm trying to create a MySQL query based on input by the user.  I have a ton of checkboxes (around 50), so I don't want to do them individually.  Here's just a few of my checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="ki67" />  ki67<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="myc" />  myc<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="mta1" />  mta1<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="mvd/cd34" />  mvd/cd34<br><br>
```

I then run them through PHP to tell the user what has been checked:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
        echo $check . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Now I would like to run them through a MySQL process to display how many rows have been selected.  Here's my code for that part:

```
<?php 
//perform database query
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) ";
$query .= "FROM testdata ";

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
        $query .= "WHERE rd_$check = 1";
    }
}
```

Then later:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
}
```

The problem comes when I try to check multiple boxes.  I don't know how to concatenate more onto `$query`.  The command would have to look something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testdata WHERE rd_ki67 = 1 AND rd_myc = 1 AND ...;
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: So you can't add `and` word to you query? o_O

Comment: no because then the whole string will fail.  You'll get: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testdata AND rd_ki67 = 1 AND rd_myc = 1 AND ...

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testdata WHERE [rd_ki67 = 1 AND] [rd_myc = 1 AND] [rd_field3 = 1]` See some pattern in `[]`?

Comment: Thanks!  That works, except for the last part where it will tack on an AND and the string will fail.  Sorry!  I'm very new to programming!

Comment: So make some  `substr` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
>   foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
>     $query .= "WHERE rd_$check = 1";
>   }
> }
> ```

This results in a query string with multiple `WHERE` clauses (`WHERE condition WHERE condition WHERE ...`) which isn't correct.

One solution is to let PHP's [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function glue the subexpressions together:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
  $wheres = array();
  foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
    $wheres[] = "rd_$check = 1";
  }
  $query .= 'WHERE ' . implode (' AND ', $wheres);
}
```

Another way to end the `AND`-chain is to add an always-true expression at the end:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
  $query .= 'WHERE ';
  foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
    $query .= "rd_$check = 1 AND ";
  }
  $query .= '1';
}
```